# Determine object type at run time - C#

Tags: c#, oop

I have the 2 sub classes called CalIntEvent and CalExtEvent which have two properties called custId and roomNumber. The classes inherit from CalEvent.

I have the below code but cannot access the derived class properties. How do I access these?

```
CalEvent newEvent;   
while (userAns != '1' && userAns != '2')
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter 1 for Internal Event or 2 for External Event: ");
    userAns = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

}

if (userAns == '1')
{
    newEvent = new CalIntEvent();

}
else
{
    newEvent = new CalExtEvent();
    newEvent.custId = 2;// issue is here<<<<<<
}
newEvent.location = GetUserInput(Field.Location, "Please enter a location");
newEvent.title = GetUserInput(Field.Title, "Please enter a title");
newEvent.description = GetUserInput(Field.Description, "Please enter a description");
```

Comment: Why don't you pass the `custId` via the constructor of `CalExtEvent`?

Comment: Or initialize it when you create the object like this: `newEvent = new CalExtEvent() { custId  = 2};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `custId` is defined on `CalExtEvent`, then you cannot access it from a variable of type `CalEvent`.

What you can do is to initialize that property upon the construction of `CalExtEvent`. Here is an example:

```
newEvent = new CalExtEvent() { custId = 2};
```